# Exist some relationship between irradiance units and wavelenght of the incident sunlight?

Tags: visible-light, sun, photons

Exist some relationship between irradiance units and wavelength of the incident sunlight?
What about irradiance? I want to establish a relationship between wavelength and irradiance, because I would try to model photosynthesis on Vensim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunlight as this gives the irradience of sunlight as a function of wavelength. The spectrum is very similar to a black body temperature of 5,600K.

I wasn't sure from your question if you were asking about the units used for irradience. The units used in the Wikipedia article (and in the [ASTM](http://rredc.nrel.gov/solar/spectra/am1.5/) page it references) are power per square metre per nanometre of bandwidth. For example a value of 1.5 at 400nm means that the total power of all the light between 400nm and 401nm is 1.5W/m$^2$. To model photosynthesis you need to multiply the spectrum by the absorption spectrum of chlorophyll then integrate across all wavelengths to get the total power per square metre.